# How do install Chromium on openELEC?

Tags: kodi, openelec, chromium

I am using openELEC and I would like to install a non-text based web browser and when I look in the add-ons it only has text based browser. How can I install a proper browser like Chromium or Firefox?

Comment: Please note that this is not a "how to do" or a "tutorial" site. More efforts you show in question will get more attention from established users. Tell us what you've done to solve your problem and what problems you're facing. Btw, did you try using `sudo apt-get install chromium` ?

Comment: I have am in openELEC so I can't find a terminal!

Comment: Then why is there a Chromium Launcher in unofficial openelec RPi repository

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenELEC appears to be an intentionally confined, minimal operating system.  I assume it is simple to use, partially because you cannot do much with it beyond Kodi.

Part of this is that it does not have much of a "package management" system.  You cannot install a vast range of software the way you could on Raspbian; you are limited to the various "add-ons".  These unofficially do include chromium, but in [the announcement for this](http://openelec.tv/forum/chromium-browser/69999-chromium-browser-added-to-unofficial-repository):

> As promised, I have compiled chromium-browser for you. only x86_64
>   build is available.
>
> **There will be NO RPi build.** please dont ask me to do it.

This announcement does look to be editable, as it was created 18 months ago and changed ~last March.  So presumably that has not changed. A [more recent announcement](http://openelec.tv/forum/128-addons/77591-chromium-html5-guide-for-netflix-amazon-prime) about an HTML 5 video and Netflix plugin notes:

> ARMs are not supported by Chromium, sorry!

All pis are ARM.

Since there does not seem to be much else about openELEC and chromium around, I think you are out of luck.

There are chromium binaries for the pi, however, as the current Raspbian includes v. 22.  It also includes Iceweasel, which is firefox "rebranded" (the issue is literally the licensing of the logo), albeit in a slightly old version (31.8).  But you won't be able to install these in openELEC.

Comment: Indeed - OpenELEC is not a general purpose OS, but rather a specialized Multimedia platform. If you want to have Kodi AND be able to run Chromium - you're better of installing Raspbian, then putting Kodi on it and doing a `sudo apt-get install chromium`.

Comment: The [Kodi.tv Forums](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=221127&page=2) have a [couple discussions](http://openelec.tv/forum/chromium-browser/69999-chromium-browser-added-to-unofficial-repository?start=240) where folks are asking about ARM & RPi support for Chromium.  So far, it's all just talk & nobody mentions having been able to build it yet.  There are some other folks who recommend going with plain Raspbian which does have Chromium, and installing Kodi on top.

Comment: Thanks goldilocks :) You were great! Gave me all the info!

Answer (score -3):

You can't, Kodi/Openelec is more of a media center rather than an OS. Sorry.

Comment: With all do respect what did this add to the existing answer?